# jQuery click events erratic, placeholder stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm messing around with porting an image selection tool into jQuery. I'm having a couple little issues that are annoying me--

First, the sortable placeholder appears to be stuck at the top of the UL-- it doesn't move down to show the proposed new position if the item were dropped.

Second, the click events attached to the buttons don't fire reliably-- sometimes they work fine, other times it takes 2, 3 or 4 clicks before they fire.

I have been reading a ton of tutorials and the jQuery docs, and I believe I've done this properly, but I'm sure there's better ways to handle what I've attempted.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the behaviour.  Any help appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2tRW/9/

Comment: i'm using chromium and the placeholder function as expected, the second problem seems that the drag start not only the image, but everywhere inside the li element and is overriding the click on the button.

Comment: The fist problem seems to resolve itself if you get rid of the CSS you're using in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested the first problem with

- ie9 (the placeholder work as expected if the document is loaded in ie8 compatibility mode)
- chromium21 (on a pc works and on another doesn't, i'm disappointed)
- opera11

the placeholder works as expected, the second problem is that you need to click exactly on the <i> element, if you click on the button but not on the image it just scroll to the top of the page.

this will fix the problem, change

```
$("#sortable").on("click", "i.icon-pencil", function(e) {
```

to

```
$("#sortable").on("click", "a.btn:has(i.icon-pencil)", function(e) {
```

EDIT:
FOUND IT

you have `float:left;` (it's in the bootstrap-combined.min.css for .span12) for all your li element but not for the highlight

add it in your fiddle and it will work.

it worked at home on ie cause i have the compatibility always set to IE8 now i get rid of that setting and it doesn't work. by the way ie8 doesn't apply `float:left` to `display:list-item;`

Comment: thanks! That fix does work. I also appreciate the details on why it failed. However, I cannot duplicate the placeholder functionality-- it still fails to work in Chrome and FF. Did you make any modifications to that code?

Comment: no, i entered the jsfiddle and tryed. i don't have FF at the moment but it function even in opera11..

Comment: the first issue now represent itself in ie9 and chrome21, i'm disappointed. on my home pc it works, on my office pc it doesn't

Comment: @julio have you tried the edited answer? i'm writing this 'cause i'm not sure how stackoverflow handle the edit to the answer...